# Access a value from a separate function

Tags: c++

```
class FinalList {
    Location List[20];
    int MaxSize;
    int Size;


public:
    FinalList()
    {
        MaxSize = 20;
    }

    void RunIt();
    void Show();
    void Mean();
    void Menu();
};


void FinalList::Mean()
{
    int K;
    double Total;
    double Average;

    for(K=0 ; K < Size ; K++)
        Total += List[K].Value;

    Average = Total / Size ;
    cout << "Average: " << Average << endl;
}

void FinalList::Show()
{
    int Count;

    for(Count = 0; Count < Size ; Count++)
        List[Count].Display();

    cout << "Average: " << Average << endl;
}
```

I can calculate the average value from the array in `Mean()`.  But how can I later access this value in `Show()`?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `Size`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either store it in an instance variable (like you're doing with `MaxSize`) or make `Mean()` return the average value instead of just printing it out.

If you make `Mean()` return the average, then you can call it in your `Show()` function like this:

```
cout << "Average: " << Mean() << endl;
```

Comment: I got it to work both ways.  Can I run the mean function with having to enter "Mean" into my command menu?  For example can I get it to run the Mean() function when I run the "Show" command?

Comment: Or perhaps after I enter the values into the array in the input() function?

Comment: For some reason the Average value is not being calculated correctly.  I am calling it in the Show() function.

Comment: @redcat: Probably because your `Size` variable is not being set anywhere.